# While installing deb file on debian using apt, how version field of dependency packages affects package installation like >=, <= etc?

Tags: debian-packaging

Below is 3rd party deb package control file. I am not allowed to modify this file.

I have **libssl1.1** installed in my VM(debian:buster-slim). when I try to install this 3rd party deb file, I am getting below error

> ThirdPartyPackage : Depends: libssl1.0.2 (>= 1.0.2d) but it is not installable

Actually libssl1.1 is greater than 1.0.2d, still its complaining why ? why libssl1.1 is not being checked for this 3rd party deb package installation ?

````
cat DEBIAN/control 
```
Package: ThirdPartyPackage
Version: 3.0.300+1
Architecture: amd64
Maintainer: ThirdPartyPackage@ThirdPartyPackagemail.com
Installed-Size: 845
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14), libgcc1 (>= 1:3.0), libstdc++6 (>= 5.2), libssl1.0.2 (>= 1.0.2d)
Section: libs
Priority: extra
Description: Its my lib.
```
````

Answer (score 1):

Your ThirdPartyPackage depends on a package called `libssl1.0.2` with a version number greater than or equal to `1.0.2d`. Yes, the version number on your `libssl1.1` package is greater than `1.0.2d`, but `libssl1.1` is *not* interchangeable with `libssl1.0.2`. They are different libraries, with different SONAMEs, which indicates incompatible ABIs. A program linked against libssl 1.0.2 will not run with libssl 1.1. This incompatibility is also why the packages have different names.

Unfortunately, `libssl1.0.2` is fairly old at this point. It is still supported in Debian 9 (“Stretch”) as of now (https://packages.debian.org/libssl1.0.2), but no other Debian releases, and no current Ubuntu releases (https://packages.ubuntu.com/libssl1.0.2). It is also no longer supported upstream unless you purchase a [support contract from OpenSSL Software Services](https://www.openssl.org/support/contracts.html).